# Worldwide population density data not grouped by country?

Tags: data, population

Are there any data sources available, preferably freely (but not necessarily), which show population density without regard to country or constituency boundaries of any sort?

I'd like to analyze a map which shows the human concentration as accurately as possible, without "blurring" it by country or other similarly large areas, and instead using a grid of some sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the best gridded data sets is CIESIN's Gridded Population.

See http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/gpw/aboutus.jsp#aboutTable for more details. The best resolution is 30 Arc seconds.

Comment: Awesome! Also, for anyone who might want a preview, there's a ready-made density map available [here (pdf)](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/gpw/maps/globaldens.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

[**LandScan**](http://www.ornl.gov/sci/landscan/index.shtml) might be another alternative.

> The dataset has 20,880 rows and 43,200 columns covering North 84
>   degrees to South 90 degrees and West 180 degrees to East 180 degrees.
>
> The dataset has a spatial resolution of 30 arc-seconds and is output
>   in a geographical coordinate system - World Geodetic System (WGS) 84
>   datum. The 30 arc-second cell, or 0.008333333 decimal degrees,
>   represents approximately 1 km2 near the equator.

More info in [documentation](http://www.ornl.gov/sci/landscan/landscan_documentation.shtml).